# Open API Generator. What is the difference between rust and rust-server clients?

Tags: rust, documentation, openapi, openapi-generator

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator

Generating a 'rust' client stub.

Generating a 'rust-server' client stub.

What's the difference between them. I feel like the 'rust' client is outdated, it doesn't have any examples and the code generated is lacking in certain areas compared to 'rust-server'. Is the reason for the 'rust' client to allow users to customise the client more or has it just been abandoned? If it is still being supported then when would you use one over the other?

Also the 'rust' client's README talks about itself being a server which only adds to the confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `rust` client generator was created first. For your feedback on the `rust` client generator, please let us know via github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/new. `rust` client supports multiple libraries that you want to try:

```
library
    library template (sub-template) to use. (Default: hyper)
        hyper - HTTP client: Hyper.
        reqwest - HTTP client: Reqwest.
```

`rust-server` generator comes with both server and client generators. There were discussions to consolidate the client part of `rust-server` into `rust` client generator but no one has time to perform the consolidation.

Comment: also worth mentioning that both of them provide VERY old dependencies, including futures 0.1 and very old OpenSSL. They in dire need of upgrading.

Comment: +1 to @Paul-SebastianManole comment. Recently tried generating stubs and was hit with a whole array of OpenSSL and other issues. Had to resort to using older machines. Also the code that is generated is very low-level using Hyper.

Comment: I think the community is building around other libraries like paperclip for OpenAPI and Rust. There are also other efforts around popular libs and frameworks like one for Rocket or Actix. Just search by keywords on lib.rs.